# The circuit modeling a surge test

Tags: passive-networks

In the surge test as far as I know, a capacitor is charged to a high voltage and is discharged via an RL load. The voltage is a decaying sinusoidal across the capacitor. This is the general picture I have about this test. Does anyone know about the equivalent circuit of the surge test. My concern is how the high dc voltage across the capacitor does not damage the low impedance motors during the surge test.

Comment: The only way the *voltage* from the capacitor is going to damage the motor is if you initially charged it to be so high that it exceeds the motor's insulation voltage. Otherwise, the other way is if the the surge current is too high, which is really unlikely considering how quickly the signal decays and the fact that the motor is a big hunk of copper and steel that needs to heat up.

Comment: It is a surge test, but it must use reasonable numbers. There's different damage mechanisms and time matters for some of them.  The problem is the question is super vague. [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: All - *Please be nice* and comply with the site's [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) (CoC) in everything you write. Nothing snarky / sarcastic / condescending (or worse). Some comments here were deleted / edited after being flagged (or other reasons). [Polite constructive criticism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756) is allowed in comments - with the emphasis on *polite* & *constructive*. Don't answer the question in comments. Also please check especially that a comment still complies with the CoC, if it includes the words "you" or "your". Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the energy stored in the capacitor is very low. Hence it does not damage the load. But if given for the longer duration it may certainly damage the load.

Comment: Thanks for the useful physics based answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that easy finding an open source hardware Surge Tester.

See this:
https://www.google.com/search?q=surge+tester+circuit&client=ms-android-hmd-rev2&prmd=isvxn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJjfON-Jf0AhXO8LsIHT-cDM0Q_AUoAXoECAIQAQ&biw=412&bih=756&dpr=2.63

---

7 years ago I bought an EFT tester from ebay which was used in a test lab. It costed 250 USD and still works and has an output resistance of 50 Ohm.

I suggest you to buy one or design on LTSpice a voltage source with 50 Ohm output resistance that replicates the waveforms of the tester.